# Dynamically add/remove datatable column&data using ajax. [works on page load but I change list via ajax it's has error]

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, datatable

I'm using a custom list to determine what are data's needs to be shown in datatable via ajax.[I add btn in same page upon click in modal I show fields list in checkbox, saving it via ajax and reloading datatable js fn.] so, If the user make changes in a custom list. datatable needs to repopulated with more/fewer fields depends custom list.

My current code I manage to modify it to dynamic list but it works when I reload page. update saving list and ajax function call. I'm facing issues like:
when adding new field:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style')
when I remove field:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'mData')

I try to empty table and when I log data it's showing currently but still getting error. I can;t figure why thead and tbody data not reloading currently using ajax. Please advise.
**my blade:**

```
<table class="dt-responsive table datatable border-top" id="employee_table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <!-- @foreach($custom_field_list as $custom_field) 
                    <th scope="col">$custom_field->field_name</th>
                    @endforeach
                    <th scope="col">Actions</th> -->
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>

            </table>
```

**my js for saving and tigger datatable fn:**

```
$(".SubmitEmpFieldListForm").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
        client_id = $('#employee_dropdown_clients').val();
        var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("createEmpFieldListForm"));
        formData.append('client_id', client_id);
        $.ajax({
            url: "/hrm/employees/custom_fields_list",
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            //data: name,
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.success.length > 0) {
                    $("#CreateEmpFieldListModal").modal("hide");
                    fetchEmployeeList("update");
                    swal("Done!", "Added succesfully!", "success");
                }
            },
            error: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
        });
    });
```

my js fn for loading datatable. (work when I reload the page)

```
function fetchEmployeeList(type) {
    if (document.getElementById("employee_table")) {
        var useroptions = {
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            lengthMenu: [
                [10, 25, 50, 100],
                [10, 25, 50, 100],
            ],
            iDisplayLength: 25,
            order: [1, "desc"],
            destroy: true,
            stateSave: true,
            ajax: {
                url: "/hrm/employees/getemployees",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "GET",
                data: function (data) {
                    console.log("getemployees");
                    var client_id = $('#employee_dropdown_clients').val();
                    data._token = "{{csrf_token()}}";
                    data.client_id = client_id;
                    
                },
            },
            columns: [],
        };

        
        // Fetch column names from the database
        $.ajax({
            url: '/hrm/employees/getcolumndata',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
                $("#employee_table thead tr").empty();
                $("#employee_table tbody").empty();
                $.each(response, function(key, value) {
                    console.log("f::"+value.field_name);
                    var column = {
                        data: value.field_name,
                        title: value.field_name,
                    };
                    // Check if the column is an action column
                    if (value.field_name === 'Actions') {
                        column.bSortable = false;
                    }
                    useroptions.columns.push(column);
                });
                
                // Create the datatable
                if (type == "initial") {
                    useroptions.stateSave = false;
                    var employeeTable = $("#employee_table").DataTable(useroptions);
                } else {
                    var employeeTable = $("#employee_table").DataTable(useroptions);
                }
                
                // Bind the search event to the search input
                $("#employee_table_filter input").unbind();
                $("#employee_table_filter input").bind("keyup", function (e) {
                    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                        employeeTable.search(this.value).draw();
                    }
                });
                
                // Add a responsive class to the datatable container
                $("#employee_table").parent().addClass("table-responsive");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**My controller:**

```
public function getemployees(Request $request)
    {
        $customFields = '';
        $customFields = DB::table('employees_custom_field_list')
        ->select('table_name', 'field_name')
        ->get()
        ->toArray();
        $fieldName = '';
        $columns = array();
        foreach($customFields as $key => $field) {
            $table = $field->table_name;
            $fieldNameUpdate[] = $field->field_name;
            $fieldName = $field->field_name;
            $columns[$key] = $table.'.'.$fieldName;
        }
        $limit = $request->input('length');
        $start = $request->input('start');
        $order = $columns[$request->input('order.0.column')];
        $dir = $request->input('order.0.dir');
        $checkjoin = EmployeeCompanyDetail::where('client_id',$request->input('client_id'))->first();
        if($checkjoin != null || !empty($request->input('client_id'))){
            $dbdata = EmployeeBasicDetail::select('employees_basic_details.id');
            $dbdata = $dbdata->leftJoin('employees_company_details', 'employees_basic_details.id', '=', 'employees_company_details.employee_id');
            foreach($customFields as $field) {
                $table = $field->table_name;
                $fieldName = $field->field_name;
                $dbdata = $dbdata->addSelect($table.'.'.$fieldName);
            }
        }else{
            $dbdata = EmployeeBasicDetail::select('employees_basic_details.id');
            foreach($customFields as $field) {
                $table = $field->table_name;
                $fieldName = $field->field_name;
                $dbdata = $dbdata->leftJoin($table, 'employees_basic_details.id', '=', $table.'.employee_id')
                            ->addSelect($table.'.'.$fieldName);
            }
        }

        $totalData = $dbdata->count();
        $totalFiltered = $totalData;
        
        $dbdata = $dbdata->offset((int) $start);
        $dbdata = $dbdata->limit($limit);
        $dbdata = $dbdata->orderBy($order, $dir);
        $employeeData = $dbdata->get()->toArray(); 
        
        if (!empty($employeeData)) {
            $auth_user = Auth::user();
            $auth_role = $auth_user->currentRole(); 
            $data = array();
            foreach ($employeeData as $employee) {
                $encEmployee_id = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::encrypt($employee['id']);
                $nestedData = [];
                foreach ($customFields as $key => $field) {
                    if (array_key_exists($field->field_name, $employee)) {
                        $nestedData[$field->field_name] = '<a href="/hrm/employees/'.$encEmployee_id.'/view" >'.$employee[$field->field_name].'</a>';
                    }
                }

                
                $data[] = $nestedData;
            }
        }
        //dd($data);
        $json_data = array(
            "draw" => intval($request->input('draw')),    
            "recordsTotal" => intval($totalData),
            "recordsFiltered" => intval($totalFiltered),
            "data" => $data,
            "header" => $fieldNameUpdate,
        );
        echo json_encode($json_data);
        

    }

    public function getcolumndata()
    {
        $auth_user = Auth::user();
        $client_id=$auth_user->client_id;
        $custom_field_list = EmployeeCustomFieldList::where(['client_id'=>$client_id,'user_id'=>$auth_user->id])->get();
        return $custom_field_list;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this issue. problem is datatable not refreshing when I make next call so I found the following code in the internet and it's solve the issue.

```
if ( $.fn.DataTable.isDataTable( '#employee_table' ) ) {
        $('#employee_table').DataTable().destroy();
        $('#employee_table').empty();
     };
```